# How to make firing "enter key" event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyevent

I am working on something little app for sign-in automation.
It is like filling in the sign-in id, password inputs, and then pressing enter to submit.
I tried `click()`, `submit()` on the button element, but it's not working.
All I want is just fire the `enter key event` after filling the inputs, but many source codes are about `get the keyboard event` which I don't need to.

Is it impossible that press enter key event??

Comment: No, it's not impossible but could be meaningless as you're not giving time to the particular User to correct anything wrong there and for no reason, your server will experience more load. One thing more I didn't downvoted

Comment: call the function which handles keyboard events.

Comment: @ash  The application I am working on is, we already have user's sign-in information for specific website. It's like we do for sign-in, instead of the users sign-in individually.  It's kind of about automation for a deployment system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var element = document.getElementById(/* Element */);

element.addEventListener("keydown", fuction(e) {
    if(e.key == "Enter") {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: it's not like I can get the key event... I will just fill the inputs and should fire the key press event within 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: Oh, what you need is to fire the event without pressing the key.

Comment: yes that's what I need. I never thought it would be this hard to find answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML `form` for this. Just wrap your inputs inside form and set `onsubmit` event. After you fill up the email and pass, `enter` will trigger the `onsubmit`.

Here is a simple example:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted");
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, I cannot modify any HTML, because it's not my website. it's like I want to make an automatic sign-in function in stackoverflow.com with the users information that I already provided.

Comment: Well if you want a fully automated solution for login in user to any website, you can follow this guide https://codedec.com/tutorials/how-to-automate-login-from-using-puppeteer/. This will open a new tab in your browser. So the cookies and other login information will be there.

Comment: You can create a function that has a timer, and when you enter the page this function will be called. When the timer expires, ``window.onKeyDown({key: "Enter")`` is called and that's it.